# access shared folder or files in iPad

Tags: ipad

how to access shared folder or files located on a LAN or Ad-Hoc from iPad over Wi-Fi Connection

is this possible ?

if this possible, please share your idea with me.

can anyone help me out?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent worked on it. But it looks fairly simple. Read following document. You can enable UIFileSharingEnabled option to share "Documents" folder of your iPad App. Try it out. Good luck.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1